# Does Newark (EWR) have a hotel actually in the airport?

Tags: hotels, ewr

Does Newark (EWR) have a hotel actually in the airport?

Perhaps in Terminal B?

(Interestingly, I just could not find this information, despite knowing how to use a browser/google.)

Failing that, the best one for a Terminal B departure?

Comment: Are you looking for an airport in the terminal, or just something adjacent to the airport? I'm not familiar with any hotels actually within the terminal at US airports except MIA, but EWR, ORD, and a few others have hotels that are walking distance from the terminals.

Comment: I didn't know such questions are welcomed here. Who are we? Trivago?  :D

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's the [Newark Marriott](https://www.marriott.com/hotels/travel/ewrap-newark-liberty-international-airport-marriott/), which while not inside the airport is about as close as you can get. It's on the other side of the parking areas from the terminal as shown in the [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/search/newark+marriott+hotel/@40.6912717,-74.1821758,814m/data=!3m1!1e3) image below. The $195 tag marks the hotel location across the parking lot from Terminal B.

[image: overview of Newark Airport from Google Maps.]

They do have a shuttle to the airport, though on the couple of occasions I've stayed here before a very early morning departure, I've walked through the parking lot and across the road to and from the hotel. Note that this was very little traffic at the time. Crossing the road at other times and/or with a lot of luggage might not be recommended, it's not really a pedestrian friendly crossing.

Here's a close-up shot of the road between the parking lot and hotel.

[image: Close up of crossing to hotel]

There are other hotels close by with airport shuttle service, but this is the closest option I'm aware of. (And likely to be most expensive.)

Comment: This is what a superior response looks like: not only does it answer the question, it  'reads between the lines'

Comment: Some hotels allow you to prearrange the shuttle service outside of normal hours. I've done this at a low budget motel, so it is likely to work at nicer places. You just gotta ask instead of waiting around.

Comment: I can confirm that it would take **maybe 1, 1.5 minutes** to walk from the "front" of the airport across to the hotel.   (It is hardly worth waiting for their own shuttle, but you could.)  Book this hotel if at all possible.  The shuttle hotels are a nightmare. But the Marriott is usually packed so book early.

Answer (score 1):

The Newark Liberty Marriott is in the airport. To walk to it you have to go through the parking lots.

Comment: Play Frogger on the busy (depending on the time of the day) airport road or take the hotel shuttle.

Comment: Right. You can walk over there in 1-2 minutes.  A hot tip at EWR is that the insane hotel shuttle system **leaves from a psychotic location - gain full information before proceeding**.  Allow **absolute minimum** 1.5 hours to get from your plane to the hotel, including trains etc etc.